# How to read XML content from window.open into string?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to read XML content from window.open into a string variable s like this via a bookmarklet:

```
javascript: (function() { s=window.open('https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/secureKnowledgeRss'); s=s.document; alert(s); })();
```

However, alert just shows '[object HTMLDocument]' instead of the real XML content.
Alternatively, is there any way to change the doctype of window.open to HTML in order to show the XML data as simple plain text?

I also tried this code:

```
javascript: (function() { s=window.open('https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/secureKnowledgeRss'); var xml = new XMLSerializer(); var str = xml.serializeToString(s.document);; alert(str); })();
```

but it just returns:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting HTMLDocument to a printable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664184/converting-htmldocument-to-a-printable-string)

Comment: No. I updated the description.

Comment: You can’t read it across different origins

Comment: But browser extensions can perform this task, too (i.e. changing XML rss into readable HTML). Examples: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/rsspreview/ or https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/feed-preview/

Answer (score 0):

A live example [here](https://www.taosdev.com/bookmarklet-devkit/#EQCghgzgngdgxgAgGYFd4BcCWB7GCQCUCA3gDp4KVy4ToIQIC8CYA7mJnUgKbpwAWIAOT906AA4QAXAHoZEFOPHYATn24x03FQDoB3OAGtlmTXuwBbeYuVq4GrSvkGUK7gGkY2VgBtuAEwBzbgAlCAghAnJKKhpsPx0fbEDwdk56HS0AD3RCKJgAXwJCAG5gIA)

Due to CORS limitation this bookmarklet only works if your current page is https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/